# Firestore Admin SDK FieldValue.increment returning wrong value

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am getting the following error when using FieldValue.increment when running a cloud function wrapped with firebase-functions-test:

> Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document.
>
> Couldn't serialize object of type "NumericIncrementTransform" (found in field "count").
>
> Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).

Here is the code that is wrapped:

```js
  // `functions` is the firebase-functions module 
  // `firestore` is an initialized FirebaseFirestore.Firestore instance pointing to the 
  //  Firestore emulator
  const { functions, firestore } = require('../../firebase');
  const getTestRelationshipRefs = require('../utils/getTestRelationshipRefs');
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');

  module.exports = functions.firestore
    .document('orgs/{orgId}/tests/{testId}')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
      const beforeData = change.before.data();
      const afterData = change.after.data();

      const relationshipRefs = getTestRelationshipRefs(afterData, context.orgId);
      const batch = firestore.batch();
   
      if (beforeData.active === false && afterData.active === true) {
        for (const ref of relationshipRefs) {
          batch.set(
            ref,
            { count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) },
            {
              merge: true,
            }
          );
        }
      }
```

There are other questions out there that seem similar such as: [Firebase cloud function - Unhandled error Error: Update()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816018/firebase-cloud-function-unhandled-error-error-update)

But it looks like I am doing the posted solution.

There are other posts I have seen that indicate this can be the result of having different versions of `@google-cloud/firestore` in the dependency tree. I don't think that is it in this case but would be delighted to be wrong.

All of the firebase related dependencies in my package.json are:

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.5.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
"firebase-tools": "^9.6.1",
"@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^1.2.5",
"firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
```

Here is the output of `npm ls @google-cloud/firestore`

```
└─┬ firebase-admin@9.5.0
  └── @google-cloud/firestore@4.9.8
```

Why is `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment` returning the wrong value?

Comment: Is there any fix for this?

Comment: @qwales1 isn't it fixed yet?